# Looking for a compilation of heresies

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, heterodox, heresy

Is anyone aware of a book/essay/website/other that compiles all Chazalic sources that refer to heresies, heterodox ideas, minut, etc? Things such as the stories about Jesus, [Mishna Megillah 4a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Megillah.4.8?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=he), and so forth.

Comment: Sorry stackechange questions by reputation and go to the last page .

Comment: What am I supposed to see on the last page?

Comment: All the questions with negative points. They end up that way because the community rules them heretical.

Comment: Ah. Hehehe... :D. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

You can see a list of sources relating to heresy that Sefaria has compiled here:

https://www.sefaria.org/topics/heresy?tab=sources

Comment: Thanks, it's a good start.